# Why I can not excecute button or frame which was positioned out of the mainView

Tags: ios, xcode, button, uiimage, range

I would be happy if anybody could support me.
I want to make an Point & Click adventure like Monkey Island. 
Therefore I have got a problem and I hope you can help me to solve it.

The problem is, that I am using an UIImage which is out of the mainScreen. 
When the UIImage scrolls in the mainView, it is no possible to push the image. (The image is created like a button)

Here is my code: You will see my remarks within the code. Thanks in advance:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

UIView *animaitionView = [[UIView alloc] init];

UIImageView *frame1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1600, 60, 40, 40)];// here is the problem, because of the 1600 for position x 
// if I would use a x-position which is much smaller than 1600 which is within of the range of the mainview, then the singleTap_methode would be work. 
// But because of the position which is out of the mobile-display (mainView), the methode does is not working anymore.  
frame1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kreis.png"];
[frame1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


[animaitionView addSubview:frame1];

NSInteger Xspeed = 1;


singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(singleTap_methode)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action:@selector(doubleTap_methode)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

[animaitionView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[animaitionView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

}

-(void)singleTap_methode{
NSLog(@"singleTap_methode");
}

-(void)doubleTap_methode{
NSLog(@"doubleTap_methode");
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];

[self moveTimer];

}

- (void) moveTo {
animaitionView.frame = CGRectMake(animaitionView.frame.origin.x - Xspeed, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                                      [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to add the `animaitionView` to `mainView`.

try this

```
[self.View addSubview:animaitionView];
```

**Update for Example**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

UIView *animaitionView = [[UIView alloc] init];

UIImageView *frame1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1600, 60, 40, 40)]; 
.....

animaitionView.frame = frame1.frame;
[animaitionView addSubview:frame1];
[self.View addSubview:animaitionView];
```

Comment: Thanks Anbu, i checked my Code but i implemented it like you wrote. Unfortunately not.